# navigation menu top and bottom,no drop up at the bottom

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<style>
ulf {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;

}

lif {
    float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;

}

lif a, .dropbtn {

    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

lif a:hover, .dropup:hover .dropbtn {

   background-color: red;
 
 

}

lif.dropup {
    display: inline-block;

}

.dropup-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
 
}

.dropup-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 
}

.dropup-content a:hover {
background-color: #f1f1f1


}

.dropup:hover .dropup-content {
    display: block;
 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  </li><li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Sales</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Search</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Transfers</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Returns</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
 </li>
 
</ul>

<ulf>
<lif class="dropup">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Order</a>
    <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </lif>
<lif class="dropup">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Reports</a>
    <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </lif>
  <lif class="dropup">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Exports/Imports</a>
    <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </lif>
   <lif class="dropup">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Settings</a>
     <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
 </lif>
 
</ulf>

</body>
</html>
```

The top navigation is working properly. I mean the drop down is functional,but the bottom navigation isn't working. I want to do something like drop up. Can someone please check the code and give me some instruction on what i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `position: absolute;` from `.dropup-content`, and replace it with this CSS:

```
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 47px;
```

And and Bob's your uncle!

```css
ulf {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
}
lif {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}
lif a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
lif a:hover, .dropup:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}
lif.dropup {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropup-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 47px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropup-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropup-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropup:hover .dropup-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ulf>
<lif class="dropup">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Order</a>
    <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </lif>
<lif class="dropup">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Reports</a>
    <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </lif>
  <lif class="dropup">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Exports/Imports</a>
    <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </lif>
   <lif class="dropup">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Settings</a>
     <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
 </lif>
 
</ulf>

</body>
</html>
```

[CodePen example:](https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/QgbKGW)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1.) Add `bottom: 0` to `.dropup-content` to align the submenus to the bottom of their container, not the top.

2.) Add `overflow-visible` to `ulf`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

ulf {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

lif {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

lif a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

lif a:hover,
.dropup:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

lif.dropup {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropup-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
}

.dropup-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropup-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropup:hover .dropup-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Sales</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Search</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Transfers</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Returns</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <ulf>
    <lif class="dropup">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Order</a>
      <div class="dropup-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </lif>
    <lif class="dropup">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Reports</a>
      <div class="dropup-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </lif>
    <lif class="dropup">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Exports/Imports</a>
      <div class="dropup-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </lif>
    <lif class="dropup">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Settings</a>
      <div class="dropup-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </lif>

  </ulf>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow hidden from ulf, add bottom: 46px to .dropup-content to get it above the bottom nav.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<style>
ulf {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;

}

lif {
    float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;

}

lif a, .dropbtn {

    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

lif a:hover, .dropup:hover .dropbtn {

   background-color: red;
 
 

}

lif.dropup {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropup-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    bottom:46px;
   
}

.dropup-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 
}

.dropup-content a:hover {
background-color: #f1f1f1


}

.dropup:hover .dropup-content {
    display: block;
 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Sales</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Search</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Transfers</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Returns</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
 </li>
 
</ul>

<ulf>
<lif class="dropup">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Order</a>
    <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </lif>
<lif class="dropup">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Reports</a>
    <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </lif>
  <lif class="dropup">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Exports/Imports</a>
    <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </lif>
   <lif class="dropup">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Settings</a>
     <div class="dropup-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
 </lif>
 
</ulf>

</body>
</html>
```